# Criar um novo array da linha 2 do array

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho um array de 30 linhas e eu quero pegar somente o índice 1, isto é o `$arr[1]`, o que eu já consigo fazer. Na segunda linha do meu `$arr[1]`, eu tenho informações do estudante. Como eu faco para pegar somente aquele linha e transformar os valores separados por espaço em um novo array?

```
Array
(
    [Student ID] => 0
    [Student info] => McLol  CRN:Not Given  Subject:MAT  Course:2222 Section:Not Given  Desc:Research
    [Total Correct Responses] =>    
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
tenta isso:

Array
(
    [Student ID] => 0
    [Student info] => McLol  CRN:Not Given  Subject:MAT  Course:2222 Section:Not Given  Desc:Research
    [Total Correct Responses] =>    
)

$new_array = explode(" ",$arr[1]['Student info']); /*o primeiro parâmetro você define o delimitador no seu caso o espaço, 
e o segundo você a string que você quer analisar;*/
```

> Conforme: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

Comment: Valeu @Rodrigo! Essa isso mesmo que eu precisava.

Comment: @J.Ty valeu mano sucesso ai no seu projeto.